# Why is the Spring Boot GraphQL QueryMapping annotation not found?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to introduce GraphQL to a Spring Boot project based on the tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql). When I add the `@QueryMapping` annotation to my Controller method, IntelliJ is unable to find it, despite the fact that I've imported (I think) the correct libraries in my Gradle file.

Here is what I've imported

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-spring-boot-starter
implementation group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-spring-boot-starter'

implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-graphql'

implementation group: 'com.graphql-java', name: 'graphql-java-tools', version: '5.0.4'

implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java-extended-scalars:19.2'
```

And here is my Controller code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping; //IntelliJ cannot find this library

@Controller
public class MyController  {

    private final MyService myService;

    public MyController(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @QueryMapping//IntelliJ cannot find this annotation
    public MyDto getMyDto(final String id) {
        return myService.getMyDto(id);
    }

}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using https://start.spring.io/? You can specify dependencies, i.e. GraphQL, and download a fresh starter package that's already setup properly for Gradle or Maven.

Comment: are you able to run `./gradlew clean build`? what is the output? is project building?

Comment: @DudeGuy I'll give that a try but this is an existing project that I'd like to incorporate GraphQL into

Comment: @swapyonubuntu When I try and run a Gradle build this is the output:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.0.4.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find com.graphql-java:graphql-java-extended-scalars:19.2.
     Required by:
         project :

Comment: can you try with implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql' add to build gradle